What are the names for the AOSP boot states?
Most importantly, I'd like to know the name for the boot state wherein the device merely reports whether it is charging (or not) and how much capacity remains in its battery. However, I'd also like to know the correct name to use for when it's completely booted, in order to differentiate it from the aforementioned.
I would have expected sleep states to describe this, but initialising into a sleep state is improbable. Unexpectedly, this information is absent from official relevant documentation at https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot/boot-flow.

In case what I'm referring to isn't evident, it is the AOSP equivalent to i(Pad)OS's



which appears when an unpowered device commences charging.
